# Epoxy paint or primer/sealer?

Tags: roof, exterior, primer, sealant

I have a coarse and porous concrete rooftop, and on Friday I went to a top roof-sealing company to buy primer to cover the roof.

While talking to the salesman, he mentions that the best thing for my rooftop is the exterior epoxy paint (he recommended Behr). I asked him if the concrete would absorb the paint (what the primer's for) and he said that it would because it's *epoxy* (ie. he said that as something obvious).

The ironic thing is that the company doesn't sell epoxy paint.

He also said that I shouldn't buy a sealant because it's designed so that there is no foot traffic. In other words, once I use the sealant I can never use it or the sealant will break (his words).

What do you guys think?

My roof won't be heavily used but I'll use it.

Comment: Most paint will state what to do before, and usually mentions what primer is needed, if any.  Epoxy paint is usually recommended for cement floors.

Comment: Sounds like the cheapest option for your use.